# Android (Chrome) and playbackRate attribute

Tags: javascript, android

The attribute playbackRate doesn't working on Android (Chrome).

[Example](http://bit-test.xsrv.jp/jonathan/test2.html)

Html:

```
<h1>Video.js Example Embed <span class="playbackRate">1.0</span></h1>

  <video id="my_video_1" class="video-js vjs-default-skin" controls preload="auto" width="100%" height="268" 
  data-setup='{ "playbackRates": [0.5, 1, 1.5, 2] }'>
    <source src="http://vjs.zencdn.net/v/oceans.mp4" type='video/mp4'>
    <source src="http://vjs.zencdn.net/v/oceans.webm" type='video/webm'>
  </video>

  <div>
    <input style="width:100%" id="PlaybackRate" type="range" value="100" min="50" max="200" _step="50" />
  </div>
```

Js:

$(document).ready(function(){

```
$('#PlaybackRate').change(function(event){
  $(this).attr('value', $(this).val());
    var playbackRate = $(this).val()/100;

    $("#my_video_1").get(0).playbackRate = playbackRate;
    document.getElementById("my_video_1").playbackRate = playbackRate;

    $('.playbackRate').html(playbackRate);
});
```

});

Is there other way?
Because I need to up video speed, like 1.5 or 2.0

I think that is possible because VLC on Android can do that : [example](http://appllio.com/douga-mx-player-vs-vlc-for-android)

Thanks you!

Answer (score 1):

This has been a known issue [for some time](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=263654).  Unfortunately thus far, the playbackRate property is [simply unsupported](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Apps/Build/Audio_and_video_delivery/WebAudio_playbackRate_explained#Browser_support) for Mobile Chrome (Android) as well as IE Mobile and Opera Mobile.

It is certainly possible that this feature will become available, but of course VLC is an entirely different app from Chrome on Android.

Should this become supported, I hope someone else will comment on it here, because I too would like to know about it. :)